# Freeze Screen w/ Overlay if JavaScript isn't enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, noscript

I'd like to darken and lock the page (prevent clicking / scrolling) and have some white text saying that the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled.

I know that the proper thing to do is have everything gracefully degrade when there isn't JavaScript- but I don't want to go this route right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<noscript>
<div id="nojs-overlay">
  Please Enable Javascript to View This Site<br>
  <a href="instructions.html">Instructions on how to enable javascript</a>
</div>
</noscript>
```

The above example only loads the overlway div in case javascript is not enabled.    The selected answer will cause a flicker or delay on slow devices.

Make sure the style your nojs-overlay div (or a series of divs) to overlay the complete screen.

Comment: best use is right before </body> closing tag so that the no script doesnt really affect the page load times.